# Explanation of Leaflet Custom Icon LatLng vs XY Coordinates

Tags: leaflet

Can someone provide an explanation on how to use the Leaflet Marker Icon XY Coordinates listed here:
http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/

Is lng/lat directly mapped to x/y? For example, sometimes in game engines, the Y pixel increases in value, but goes **down** the page.
Here is it the same? I can't quite wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you mean by "*Is lng/lat directly mapped to x/y?*", but here are some explanations that should talk enough:

[image: LatLng directions and XY directions] <sub>(tile courtesy [MapQuest](http://open.mapquest.com/))</sub>

As in most image manipulation software:

- X increases from left to right
- Y increases from top to bottom

When specifying [`iconAnchor`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#icon-iconanchor) and [`shadowAnchor`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#icon-shadowanchor) for Leaflet custom icons, these directions still apply. Furthermore, like in most image software as well, the origin is the top left corner of your image.

[image: iconAnchor directions]

```js
var myIcon = L.icon({
  iconUrl: 'path/to/image.png', // relative to your script location, or absolute
  iconSize: [25, 41], // [x, y] in pixels
  iconAnchor: [12, 41]
});
```

As explained in the doc, if you specify `iconSize` but not `iconAnchor`, Leaflet will assume your icon tip is at the center of your image and position it accordingly (same for shadow).

But if you do specify **neither** `iconSize` nor `iconAnchor`, Leaflet will position your icon image "as is", i.e. as if its tip was its top left corner. Then you can apply a [`className`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#icon-classname) option and define it in CSS with negative left and top margins to re-position your image.

```js
var myIcon = L.icon({
  iconUrl: 'path/to/image.png',
  // iconSize: [25, 41],
  // iconAnchor: [12, 41], // [x, y]
  className: 'custom-icon'
});
```

```css
.custom-icon {
  margin-left: -12px; /* -x */
  margin-top: -41px; /* -y */
}
```

This usage might be more interesting when using a [`DivIcon`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#divicon), for which you may not know the size in advance, and use CSS transforms to position it.

As for the [`popupAnchor`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#icon-popupanchor), it uses the icon tip as origin, so you will most likely specify a negative `y` value, so that the popup appears above the icon.

[image: popupAnchor directions]

```js
popupAnchor: [1, -34] // [x, y]
```

Finally when adjusting your anchor values, a useful trick is to add a normal default marker at the exact same Lat/Lng location as the marker with your custom icon, so that you can compare both icon tip positions easily.

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what i was hoping for, an explanation with ms-paint style figures. Should go in official docs!

Comment: excellent explanation, thanks! i am using react-leaflet and this worked perfectly