# Custom leaflet divIcon not staying in fixed marker position when zoomed

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet

I have made a custom marker for use with leaflet maps, it seems to work fine but when I zoom in and out of the map it changes position drastically and I would like it to stay where it should with the point on the position. I have checked and tried changing anchor points and position but it just seems to make it worse so I will show you what I have and hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

I have made a JSFIDDLE here : http://jsfiddle.net/qpt02Luy/1/

and the html is :

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

and the CSS is :

```
body { padding: 0; margin: 0; } html, body, #map { z-index : 1; height: 100vh; width: 100vw; }
.location-pin {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
.location-pin img {
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
  margin: -26px 0 0 -13px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;

  background: #32383e;
}
.pin {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 0;
  background: #32383e;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -43px 0 0 -30px;

}
.pin:after {
  content: '';
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  margin: 2px 0 0 2px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;

}
```

The JS :

```
var zoom = 10;
var osmUrl='https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
var osmAttrib='Map data © <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors';
var osm = new L.TileLayer(osmUrl, {
    attribution: osmAttrib,
    detectRetina: true
});

// please replace this with your own mapbox token!
var token = 'pk.eyJ1IjoidGhlZGlnZ2xlcnVrIiwiYSI6ImNqcG9uZHM3eDAxcDk0Mm4wcjdsYXJ4YXoifQ.1WVGvW9ESiMWfk3F6g3UIA';
var mapboxUrl = 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v10/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x?access_token=' + token;
var mapboxAttrib = 'Map data © <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors. Tiles from <a href="https://www.mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>.';
var mapbox = new L.TileLayer(mapboxUrl, {
  attribution: mapboxAttrib,
  tileSize: 512,
  zoomOffset: -1
});

window.map = new L.Map('map', {
    layers: [mapbox],
    minZoom: 2,
    maxZoom: 18,
    center: [51.505, -0.09],
    zoom: 10,
    zoomControl: false

});

var myIcon = L.divIcon({
    className: 'location-pin',
    html: '<img src="https://www.faces2places.co.uk/img/jules.jpg"><div class="pin"></div><div class="pulse"></div>',
    iconSize: [30, 30],
    iconAnchor: [18, 30]
  });

  L.marker([51.5, -0.09], {icon: myIcon}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The CSS rules for your `location-pin` class (namely the `top` and `left` rules) interfere with the Leaflet positioning through [`iconAnchor`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#icon-iconanchor) option. I do not think you need them at all.

Once you remove them, the `iconAnchor` option works again as normal, and you are left with specifying appropriate values to correctly position your custom DivIcon.

As suggested in [Explanation of Leaflet Custom Icon LatLng vs XY Coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46101450/explanation-of-leaflet-custom-icon-latlng-vs-xy-coordinates/46109930#46109930), a useful trick is to add a normal default marker at the exact same Lat/Lng location as the marker with your custom icon, so that you can compare both icon tip positions easily.

In your case, `iconAnchor: [10, 33]` seems to work fine.

[image: Custom icon correctly positioned]

Updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dyc7pe4s/

Comment: Thank you, it was driving me mad!